# Adjust Word 2013 Bibliography style to display an APA citation as (firstname lastname, year) based on the source locale

Tags: xslt, ms-word

My thesis uses an APA citation. However, with research documents that is written in Thai, an inline citation must be of the form (firstname lastname, year) rather than the APA (lastname, year). This should be possible with a custom Microsoft Word 2013 bibliography style which would require an adjustment to the APA.XSL file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Bibliography\Style to include an additional logic similar to the follow:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="b:LCID='1054'">
        (Firstname Lastname, year)
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        (Lastname, year)
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I believe that the additional logic should be added in this section, and that it must involve an adjustment to xsl:template formatNameCore.

```
<xsl:variable name="author0">
</xsl:variable>
```

However, my mind is drawing a blank beyond that. I wonder if anyone could point me to a correct direction. Help is much appreciated.

[Here's the current xsl file](http://pastebin.com/F9G0e6yv).

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching (and reading), I have stumbled upon [this post](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=79283&page=3) in which all the temp1_prop_APA_*_* are specified as included below:

```
templ_prop_APA_MainAuthors_FML = %L, %f %m
templ_prop_APA_MainAuthors_FM = %f %m
templ_prop_APA_MainAuthors_ML = %L, %m
templ_prop_APA_MainAuthors_FL = %L, %f
```

Having nothing to lose; hence, I tried. While I do not know how exactly these %L, %F, or %M and their lowercase counterparts have came to be (explanations would have been nice), the expressions do work. In turn, included below is the section of adjusted code. So far, it seems to work for the purpose.

```
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationLong_FML" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
        <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
            <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
                <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %M %L'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%L, %F %M'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationLong_FM" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %M'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %M'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationLong_ML" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%M %L'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%L, %M'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationLong_FL" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %L'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%L, %F'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FML" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %M %L'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%L'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FM" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %M'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_ML" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%M %L'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%L'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FL" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$_LCID='1054'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'%F %L'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'%L'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: A full file is included [here](http://pastebin.com/GDG94fMy).

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with these templates:

```
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FML" >
  <xsl:param name="LCID" />
  <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
    <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
      <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:APA/b:CitationShort/b:FML"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ... -->
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FL" >
  <xsl:param name="LCID" />
  <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
    <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
      <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:APA/b:CitationShort/b:FL"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try:

```
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FML" >
  <xsl:param name="LCID" />
  <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
    <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
      <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:APA/b:CitationShort/b:FM"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:APA/b:CitationShort/b:FML"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ... -->
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_APA_CitationShort_FL" >
  <xsl:param name="LCID" />
  <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
    <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
      <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:APA/b:CitationShort/b:FM"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=$_LCID]/b:APA/b:CitationShort/b:FL"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't figure out where these values are getting populated, so this is the best I can do for now.

It seem safe to make this change here, instead of in the loop in `<xsl:variable name="author0">...</xsl:variable>`, as it's only ever called from there. This change won't affect your bibliography.

You may also have to modify the other `temp1_prop_APA_*_*` templates similarly.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I agree with you. I will make the adjustment in temp1_prop_APA_*_* template as you suggested. Just wish I could find out what are the definitions to those b:FML, b:FM, b:FL and such. Strangely, a search in C:/ doesn't seem to yield anything related there either.